# can svg code be assigned to a CUSTOM html entity and used in a pseudo class as content in css?

Tags: html, css, svg, html-entities

I am using the css content for some predefined ones like : `content:"\00a9";` (for the copyright symbol)

I tried to define a svg image in the html entities and use it with the content tag similarly but it doesn't work. Not sure if this is possible or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
<!ENTITY my_code "<svg id="icon-plus-outline" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" x="0" y="0"><path d="M18 10.5h-4.5v-4.5h-3v4.5h-4.5v3h4.5v4.5h3v-4.5h4.5v-3z"></path></svg>">
]>
```

and in the css

```
p::before{
 content: "&my_code";
}
```

so that the reusable icons in the page can be used easily and also the color codes can be used easily this way.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I went for a Custom Element ``<svg-icon name name="icon-plus-outline">`` to create SVG icons client-side, see https://iconmeister.github.io

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman I am actually using a sprite svg file for my icons... want to change the icon colors as per need, so only thought of this approach...

Comment: won't work, not with ``content: attr(svg)`` either. content is escaped, not parsed, easily tested with ``content: "<b>Not Bold</b>"``.

Comment: ah right... any other suitable approach to use svg images and change the color of the images dynamically (using SASS for example) ?

Comment: You can include raw SVG and style with CSS (you can target individual SVG elements with CSS selectors and set ``fill`` ``stroke`` etc.) **provided** your SVG was written to be styled by (outside) CSS. That is why I created the IconMeister Custom Element ``<svg-icon>``, it creates the SVG dynamically, this allowing to set all attributes/properties

Comment: yep, that looks good :) thank you for sharing your thoughts ... I will have to using the paths in the background with url i think for now...